# What does the $\frac{2πf}{c}$ expression mean?

Tags: waves, frequency

I'm looking at an algorithm for image generation and there's an expression I can't understand, if you could help me cast some light I'd be truly grateful.

The expression is $\frac{2πf}{c}$, where $f$ means carrier frequency and $c$ is the speed of light.

Comment: This might require more context for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That quantity looks like the wavenumber, $k$, which is given by
$$k = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$$
where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the light, and this is related to $f$ and $c$ via
$$c=f\lambda$$
This quantity is therefore a measure of the (inverse) wavelength of the light.